# Accessing Google Drive Files in Google App Engine [Shareable Link]

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, file-sharing

I have an android app that saves an image into the Google Drive and shares the weblink to my Google App Engine server (python).

```
    // Create client
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();

   // handling results after uploading
   final DriveOperationResult<Metadata> driveOperationResultHandler = new DriveOperationResult<Metadata>() {

    @Override
    public void onDriveOperationSucceeded(Metadata result) {
        try {
            // Successfully fetched metadata
            onSuccess(driveId,
                      result.getOriginalFilename(),
                      result.getWebContentLink(),
                      result.getWebViewLink(),
                      result.getAlternateLink(),
                      result.getEmbedLink());
        } finally {
            mGoogleDriveClient.disconnectAsync();
        }
    }
```

**Note:** result.getEmbedLink() always returns null. Also, result.getAlternateLink() and result.getWebContentLink() are not accessible. I am using Google Drive Android API.

I need to post the link to another server from the google app engine. How do I get a shareable link from google app engine [python] or android?

or

How do I change the permission on the link so that anyone with the link can read?

Comment: show us what you tried so far after trying the Drive api from appengine (with the library for your appengine language or with Rest), and what is failing. also clarify if its your Drive or the users drive.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you must do something like this

```
@decorator.oauth_required
def get(self):
    try:
        http = decorator.http()
        service = discovery.build("drive", "v2", http=http)

        # Make the list of every files in the user's Drive
        # Take every fields we will need after
        fields = "items(id,title,,alternateLink)
        list = service.files().list(fields=fields).execute()
```

Then use the alternateLink property to get a link that can be shared for opening the file in the relevant Google editor or viewer